# Fast simple program to add some fake dimensions on an image

Tags: linux, drawing, image-editor, clothing

I have an image with some dimensions. But I need to add one or two dimensions to it. I mean lines with circles on their ends and arrows on their other ends and with a letter in the middle of the lines. Which Linux program would be good for it? I need something free and small.

Here is the image:

[image: image of clothing needing dimensions]

Comment: Adding two dimensions, you have a 4D jacket. Many quantum theorists and particle accelerators would be very happy if they could examine it. :-)

Comment: See what dimensions I mean https://i.imgur.com/8X35PoK.png

Comment: How could you add "one or two dimensions" to it? I tought you want some software tool which generates a 3d-looking image from your 2d one. But it is not as you have shown in your image link.

Comment: Ok so I want to add lines with arrows and numbers placed on their middle. Forget dimensions... https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-DEB94C8F-064F-4E44-AB7A-D157DA166581-htm.html

Comment: I am sorry, but your question is incomprehensible. The capability to formulate comprehensible questions is a requirement to use the site network.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice. I fixed the question.

Comment: Inkscape would be able to do this, but is neither simple nor small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an ideal task for [Inscape](https://inkscape.org).

It is free, [GPL 2](https://inkscape.org/about/license/).

It runs on [Linux](https://inkscape.org/de/release/1.0.1/gnulinux/).

It's considerably small, 107 MB download size. That's less than half of Affinity Deisgner, a comparable commercial product. So it should fit on older PCs with little disk space available.

The startup time is certainly not very fast, but once started it's ok. It's a program for creating vector graphics. That is: you can edit the graphics later, whereas in a pixel graphic, your changes are more of a permanent nature. Thus, changing the graphics will be easier.

Regarding simple: well, it has a lot of options, but you needn't use them. You'll find arrows and circles quickly.